# Javascript-triggered CSS effects

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a small project where if the user enters the Konami code on a site, a filter is applied to every element (for now, will be better in the final version). Right now I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var success = function() {
            var css = 'div { -webkit-filter: blur(10px); }',
                head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                style = document.createElement('style');

            style.type = 'text/css';
            if (style.styleSheet){
                style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
            } else {
                style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
            }
        }
        var konami = new Konami(success);
    </script>
```

and I'm using `http://snaptortoise.com/konami-js/` which has successfully run when used with a redirect instead of a function (documentation says I can create a new Konami with the method shown above, or with a url string to be used as a redirect).

I've gotten javascript `alert` messages to show, but cannot implement this filter. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the class in your stylesheet:

```
.blurred {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

And then add it to your `<body>` tag:

```
var success = function() {
    document.body.className = 'blurred';
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You never append `style` to the head:

```
head.appendChild(style);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/2mTJf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `head.appendChild(style)`.

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NMetj/